# Accessing a hidden share programmatically in VB.net

Tags: windows, vb.net

I have a simple method to move a folder to a new directory

```
        Dim firstshare As String = "\\myshare\users\" & frmDeparture.txtUsername.Text
        Dim destination As String = "\\secondshare\userarchives$\" & frmDeparture.txtUsername.Text

        Try
            If Directory.Exists(firstshare) Then
                Directory.Move(firstshare, destination)
                MsgBox("Folder moved from \\firstshare\users")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error finding folder")
        End Try
```

This works fine if I set "destination" as a path like "\path\whatever", but if it's a hidden path (with the $) it doesn't work.  Is there something special I have to do in order to access a hidden share programatically?

Comment: "it doesn't work" do you get an error?

Comment: Strangely, there is no exception or compilation error.  It simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely trying to move a directory from one volume/partition to another, and you are getting this error :

> Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not
>   work across volumes

An explanation of why this is not possible is found [Here](http://www.jdsweblog.com/2010/10/directorymove-doesnt-move-files-across.html). The only way you could move directories across different volumes is to create a new directory in the destination volume and copy the files from the source. You could then delete the original files if you wish.